# Compiling a python script with Pyinstaller via terminal

Tags: python, terminal, executable, pyinstaller

I am using macOS, and Anaconda 3 in order to manage my libraries and write the script.

I want to create an executable for my script.

I am using Pyinstaller in Terminal to run the command:

`pyinstaller --onefile /Directory/file.py`

However, Terminal returns this error:

`File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-sysconfig.py", line 42, in <module>
    hiddenimports = [sysconfig._get_sysconfigdata_name()]
TypeError: _get_sysconfigdata_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'check_exists'`

How can I solve this problem; thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

`conda update conda` did not work for me, so I will just post my solution here.

First, go to python interactive shell, do

```
$ python
>> import sysconfig
>> print(sysconfig.__file__)
```

This should give you where the file locates for `sysconfig`. Then what you need to go to that file and edit the source code, for me it was `/opt/conda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py`, then find the function and change function signature for `_get_sysconfigdata_name`, what I did was make `check_exists` default to `True`.

Comment: In my case, I was not able to modify the `sysconfig.py` because it was in root folder, so I modified `hiddenimports = [sysconfig._get_sysconfigdata_name()]` to `hiddenimports = [sysconfig._get_sysconfigdata_name(check_exists=True)]` in `venvs\test\lib\site-packages\Pyinstaller\hooks\hook- distutils.py` instead

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in older versions of Anaconda. You can try to update Anaconda (in the conda terminal):

```
conda update conda
```

You can also try to remove the `sysconfig._get_sysconfigdata_name()` from the `hiddenimports` list in your .spec file and instead add `import sysconfig` in your .py file.

The following issue documentation on the pyinstaller github page may be of further help:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3192